# Mysql 8.2 command line client crashes right after starting, windows 11

Tags: mysql

I just installed Mysql 8.2, but the command line client crashes right after I start it, the service is running fine, Also added the bin path to system environment keys, I tried using CMD and it works fine.
any possible solutions?